# No descarga los reportes de rotativa en publicacion azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo mi proyecto .net framework publicado en Azure. Estoy utilizando Rotativa para generar un reporte y descargarlo en pdf. Esto funciona de forma local pero al publicarlo no lo descarga, queda cargando hasta que muestra error por exceso de tiempo.

```
public ActionResult Print(int idEmpresa,int idTipoAnio,DateTime date)
        {
            return new ActionAsPdf("Reportes",new {idEmpresa = idEmpresa, idTipoAnio = idTipoAnio, date= date})
            { FileName = "reportes.pdf" };
    }
```

Este el código que utilizo para todos los reportes y funciona en local host

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te da? (Algún LOG que tengas manejado)

Comment: ¿Cuando publico?

Comment: Todo lo que puedas para que se entienda bien la pregunta, `queda cargando hasta que muestra error por exceso de tiempo.` Esto solo indica que hubo timeout, ¿y si le extiendes el tiempo? Rotativa es una librería potente, algunos detalles requieren manejo del lado del servidor. Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Muchas gracias .Si queda cargando y ocurre  un timeout .Creo que si es un problema por el lado del servidor .¿Donde puedo encontrar algo de informacion para que pueda configurar rotativa del lado del servidor? .

Comment: Insisto, lee el contenido del enlace mostrado, te ayudará a crecer más rápido como desarrollador. Entre más datos,mucho mejor, de esa masa da datos, saldrán datos interesantes que terminarán en alguna buena pregunta. Mira: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28682110/3613462 es probable tu problema sea por el tipo de servicio que estés usando.

Answer (score 0):

Respuesta relacionada:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42705926/3613462

Del enlace:

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks

Se extrajo lo siguiente:

`Rotativa / wkhtmltopdf: requires the site to run in Basic or higher.`

Conclusión:

No se puede ejecutar `Rotativa/wkhtmltopdf` en un Free Tier o en un Shared Tier. Debe estar en una capa básica o superior.